# Why can't my JavaServer Faces App connect to my Data Resource?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jdbc

I'm learning about JavaServer Faces application, and I'm trying to deploy a few simple ones. I've successfully deployed apps that don't use a database, but I'm having trouble with ones that do.

When I first built the app locally in Netbeans, I would connect to JavaDB by first creating a JDBC connection pool, and then JDBC resource that uses that pool, through the Glassfish admin console. Then within the code, I connect to the database as follows:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/slideshow")
DataSource dataSource;
```

And here's the method where I access the database:

```
private ArrayList<Image> getImages() throws SQLException {
    if (dataSource == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");
    }

    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");
    }

    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM slideshowimages");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(new Image(rs.getString("url"), rs.getString("title"), rs.getString("description")));
    }

    connection.close();
    stmt.close();
    rs.close();

    return list;
}
```

This works fine when I run the app locally, through Netbeans. However, when I deploy it on my own server, I get the following error:

```
Table/View 'SLIDESHOWIMAGES' does not exist.
```

You can see this in action your self here: http://162.209.84.39:8080/Slideshow/.

From the Netbeans Services pane, I've been able to create a new connection to the resource on the remote server (jdbc:derby://162.209.84.39:1527/slideshow) and run SQL commands on it. Based on the output, the SQL has run successfully (I can run the query from the code from Netbeans and get the data I expect back); however, I still get that error when trying to load the page. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for that! This is modified from my actual method, which uses an if statement to determine if it has been run before, so it only accesses the database once. I know that's sloppy, but I wasn't aware of `@PostConstruct`. Thanks!

Comment: This specific problem is not related to JSF. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using a different front-end trying to interact with the DB the same way. So far it sounds like the datasource's JDBC URL is incorrect, that it doesn't refer a database containing the table of interest. However, information about how you configured the datasource is missing in the question.